# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'bulto' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF. Hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, database-migration, sqlexception

I recently migrated my DB from mysql to sqlserver and now when I try to insert data in some table thows me this error. I 'm not putting the ID manually. I guess it's that java gives me the ID to 0 automatically. I use Hibernate and this is my mapping file for this table.

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="es.rumbosistemas.sctrakker.modelo.Bulto" table="bulto">
    <id column="id" name="idBulto" type="integer">
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="company">
        <column name="company_id"/>
    </many-to-one>
    <property column="ejercicio" name="ejercicio"/>
    <property column="serie" name="serie"/>
    <property column="seq_id" name="seq_id"/>
    <property column="descripcion" name="description"/>
    <property column="type_id" name="type_id">
        <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
            <param name="enumClass">es.rumbosistemas.sctrakker.modelo.BultoType</param>
            <param name="type">12</param>
        </type>
    </property> 
    <property column="quantity" name="quantity" />
    <many-to-one name="parentBulto">
        <column name="parent_id"/>
    </many-to-one>
    <property column="included" name="included"/>
    <property column="visible" name="visible"/>
    <property column="deleted" name="deleted"/>
    <property column="date_created" name="date_created"/>
    <property column="date_updated" name="date_updated"/>
    <many-to-one name="owner">
        <column name="owner"/>
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one name="location">
        <column name="location"/>
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one name="articulo">
        <column name="articulo"/>
    </many-to-one>
</class> </hibernate-mapping>
```

And this is my Bulto.class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"handler", "hibernateLazyInitializer"})
public class Bulto implements Serializable {

private int idBulto;
private Company company;
private Calendar calendario;
private int ejercicio;
@Size(max = 50)
private String serie;
private int seq_id;
@Size(max = 50)
private String description;
@NotNull
private BultoType type_id;
private String codigoDeBarras;
private Bulto parentBulto;
private boolean included;
private boolean visible;
private boolean deleted;
private Calendar date_created;
private Calendar date_updated;
private Company owner;
private Location location;
private Articulo articulo;
private int quantity;

public Bulto() {
    this.calendario = new GregorianCalendar();
    this.date_created = new GregorianCalendar();
    this.ejercicio = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
}

public Bulto(int idBulto, Company company, Calendar calendario, int ejercicio, String serie, int seq_id, String description, BultoType type_id, String codigoDeBarras, Bulto parentBulto, boolean included, boolean visible, boolean deleted, Calendar date_created, Calendar date_updated, Company owner, Location location, Articulo articulo, int quantity) {
    this.idBulto = idBulto;
    this.company = company;
    this.calendario = calendario;
    this.ejercicio = ejercicio;
    this.serie = serie;
    this.seq_id = seq_id;
    this.description = description;
    this.type_id = type_id;
    this.codigoDeBarras = codigoDeBarras;
    this.parentBulto = parentBulto;
    this.included = included;
    this.visible = visible;
    this.deleted = deleted;
    this.date_created = date_created;
    this.date_updated = date_updated;
    this.owner = owner;
    this.location = location;
    this.articulo = articulo;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public int getIdBulto() {
    return idBulto;
}

public String getCodigoDeBarras() {
    return codigoDeBarras;
}

public void setCodigoDeBarras(String codigoDeBarras) {
    this.codigoDeBarras = codigoDeBarras;
}

public void setIdBulto(int idBulto) {
    this.idBulto = idBulto;
}

public Company getCompany() {
    return company;
}

public void setCompany(Company company) {
    this.company = company;
}

public Calendar getCalendario() {
    return calendario;
}

public void setCalendario(Calendar calendario) {
    this.calendario = calendario;
}

public int getEjercicio() {
    return ejercicio;
}

public void setEjercicio(int ejercicio) {
    this.ejercicio = ejercicio;
}

public String getSerie() {
    return serie;
}

public void setSerie(String serie) {
    this.serie = serie;
}

public int getSeq_id() {
    return seq_id;
}

public void setSeq_id(int seq_id) {
    this.seq_id = seq_id;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public BultoType getType_id() {
    return type_id;
}

public void setType_id(BultoType type_id) {
    this.type_id = type_id;
}

public Bulto getParentBulto() {
    return parentBulto;
}

public void setParentBulto(Bulto parentBulto) {
    this.parentBulto = parentBulto;
}

public boolean isIncluded() {
    return included;
}

public void setIncluded(boolean included) {
    this.included = included;
}

public boolean isVisible() {
    return visible;
}

public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
    this.visible = visible;
}

public boolean isDeleted() {
    return deleted;
}

public void setDeleted(boolean deleted) {
    this.deleted = deleted;
}

public Calendar getDate_created() {
    return date_created;
}

public void setDate_created(Calendar date_created) {
    this.date_created = date_created;
}

public Calendar getDate_updated() {
    return date_updated;
}

public void setDate_updated(Calendar date_updated) {
    this.date_updated = date_updated;
}

public Company getOwner() {
    return owner;
}

public void setOwner(Company owner) {
    this.owner = owner;
}

public Location getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(Location location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public Articulo getArticulo() {
    return articulo;
}

public void setArticulo(Articulo articulo) {
    this.articulo = articulo;
}

public int getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

}
```

And this the full error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'bulto' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:404)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:350)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1715)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:314)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2764)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3275)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:203)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:183)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:167)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:320)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:287)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:193)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:204)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:189)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:670)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:662)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:658)
at es.rumbosistemas.sctrakker.datos.InventarioDAOImpHibernate.anyadirAlInventario(InventarioDAOImpHibernate.java:32)
at es.rumbosistemas.sctrakker.presentacion.InventarioController.anyadirAlInventario(InventarioController.java:85)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at es.rumbosistemas.sctrakker.presentacion.seguridad.FilterSecurity.doFilter(FilterSecurity.java:64)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at es.rumbosistemas.sctrakker.datos.HibernateContextListenerAndFilter.doFilter(HibernateContextListenerAndFilter.java:36)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Well in order to insert identities you need to set identity insert on. Also remember identity insert can only be on for 1 table at a time!

Comment: But, i'm not putting the ID manually. I want to put the DB

Comment: Your question states you want to use an explicit value, you should clean up the question and make it clear what you are asking for. It is very hard to help you like this.